# Using ubuntu one with usb modem rather than router

Tags: ubuntu-one, usb, modem

The Ubuntu One control panel thinks that there is no internet connection when in fact there is (via Speedtouch usb modem). How can I proceed?

Comment: I connect all the time with my mobile phone and it works fine. Although I shut down Ubuntu One because I don't want it using up my mobile data.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Ubuntu One uses Network Manager to detect whether you are online.

Could it be that you are not connecting using Network Manager?